# jquery atmosphere cross domain restrictions

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp, comet, atmosphere

i'd like to connect to a comet server using jquery atmosphere plugin. Problem is the server is located on a different domain and "As of v 0.7.2, Atmosphere JQuery PubSub does not support cross domain requests. We cannot use this method for JSONP". Is there any ways to circumvent this? I'm open to any solution!

Here is the javascript code used in the given example page on the remote domain:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    function callback(response) {
        // Websocket events.
            $.atmosphere.log('info', ["response.state: " + response.state]);
        $.atmosphere.log('info', ["response.transport: " + response.transport]);

        detectedTransport = response.transport;
        $('ul').append($('<li></li>').text("Resp Status : "+response.status+" Transport : "+response.transport));
        if (response.transport != 'polling' && response.state != 'connected' && response.state != 'closed') {
        $.atmosphere.log('info', ["response.responseBody: " + response.responseBody]);
        if (response.status == 200) {
            var data = response.responseBody;
            if (data.length > 0) {
               dataArray = eval("("+data+")");

               $.each(dataArray, function(index, value){
                 var output = '';
                 var dipData = value;
                 for (property in dipData) {
                    output += property + ': ' + dipData[property]+'; ';
                 }

                 $('ul').append($('<li></li>').text(dipData.__publicationName+":"+output));
               });
            }
        }
        else{

        }
        }
    }

       // As of v 0.7.2, Atmosphere JQuery PubSub does not support
       // cross domain requests. We cannot use this method for JSONP
       $.atmosphere.subscribe(document.location.toString() + 'webcast', callback);
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option may be to stand up a Node.js proxy on your domain to broker your requests to the external domain.

Comment: Thanks, I have never touch node.js before. Could you give me an example of how it'd be implemented?  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for node.js. Nginx is also quite simple as a simple proxy server.

Comment: I'm using nginx on the server, maybe it'd be the best approach then; Could you give me an exemple of how it'd work ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is: using CORS for none IE browsers and XDR or Cross Domain Request.
You just have to modify the HTTP header and use Allow_Access.